# QR Generator for Static Page

Tags: php, qr-code

I have a problem on generating QR code in static page.

I am developing a event management system. 
For each event, I want to place a QR code including event's Name, date, time, venue and short description.
Please give me some ideas how to do this.
Which API I have to use? And how can I pass data to that QR server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Google's chart API.
For more information about how to use this check out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes).

Example:

```html
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com&choe=UTF-8&chs=200x200" />
```